# Can generics be used with android room Entities?

Tags: android, kotlin, polymorphism, android-room

Consider the following `Entity`:

```kotlin
@Entity(tableName = "media")
data class Media(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true) val id: Long = 0,
    // Stored as a JSON blob in SQLite using some TypeAdapter magic
    val content: Content,
) {
    sealed class Content {
        data class Image(val width: Int, val height: Int): Content()
        data class Video(val framerate: Int): Content()
    }
}
```

To access `Media.Content.Image.width` I would have to do

```kotlin
val media: Media = // { ... } - returns image media
(media.content as Media.Content.Image).width
```

This gets old pretty quick and seems error-prone.

With generics I would be able to do something like the following:

```kotlin
@Entity(tableName = "media")
data class Media<T: Media.Content>(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true) val id: Long = 0,
    val content: T,
) {
    sealed class Content {
        data class Image(val width: Int, val height: Int): Content()
        data class Video(val framerate: Int): Content()
    }
}
```

```kotlin
val media: Media<Media.Content.Image> = // { ... } - returns image media
media.content.width
```

However, this style seems problematic:

```
error: Cannot use unbound fields in entities.
    private final T content = null;
error: Cannot figure out how to save this field into database. You can consider adding a type converter for it.
    private final T content = null;
```

I'm not sure what a TypeConverter for `T` would look like - is there a way to get Room to handle this type of generics or is it simply not supported?

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a reified inline method that handles the type cast?
Since you already don't have any type safety guarantees from the compiler.

Even better would be to also serialize the type and use a switch statement to
handle every possible returned type.

```kotlin
inline fun <reified T> Media.contentAccess(): T {
  return this.content as T
}

val media: Media = Media(id = 1, content = Media.Content.Image(width = 1, height = 1))
media.contentAccess<Media.Content.Image>().width
```

Comment: This is an option I have looked at. I have some problems with it though. 1. you cannot make e.g. a `List<Media<Media.Content.Image>>`, 2. you have two properties for the same data, 3. `contentT<Media.Content.Image>()` is just as long (or longer) as `content as Media.Content.Image` (why not just use `as` in the first place?), 4. Now you need to use the generic method for _each access_. By using `as` directly you can make use of smart casts for consecutive `.content` uses.

Comment: I hear all your concerns and they are totally valid. The problem you are facing is that the Entity declaration is fundamentally a storage schema similar to a SQL DDL script and not a transport layer entity. That means that the type of T: Media.Content is a characteristic of the way you query the db. If you want to create a more ergonomic api then your DAO should probably offer a mapper that converts Media to a MediaWrapper<T> when you can utilize the context of your query to expose the correct semantics.